# Can't handle Intent properly in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing a Data Entry system wherein the user can save, search and update data. In this activity, I'm using EditTexts, spinners and a button (to search for Clinic Names). When the user is finish filling those EditTexts and spinners, he can search for Clinic using the Button. This button will trigger the intent to another activity.

The other activity has a EditText(with TextFilters and can search for Clinic) and a ListView which shows the results upon search. When the result shows up, the user can click the ListView Items and that will trigger to the previous activity and will fill-out the Clinic Name to the EditText assigned to it.

My problem is when the user clicked the ListView item, and goes to the previous activity, those data from the EditTexts and Spinners were cleared up!

`I want to happen is that, when I search for Clinic Name and goes to the another activity, those data that was already filled-out`**`will not be cleared or lost`**`.`

MainActivity.java

```
    //Getting clinic address
    txt_DClinic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchClinicActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }

    });
```

SearchClinicActivity.java

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            TextView tv_clinicId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewId);
            String clinicID = tv_clinicId.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("clinic_id", clinicID);
            intent.putExtra("signal", "2");
            intent.putExtra("from", "SearchClinic");
            intent.putExtra("LoginOrSearch", "ImSearchClinic");
            finish();
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are clicking on list item and opening intent. set flag to intent.

```
intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
```

and see if its working or not.

if its not than try one thing is that. you are passing extras in intent. at that time pass the values for edittext and item number of spinner. and in onCreate method of Main activity set text of edittext with that extra. and set selected value for spinner.

```
edtTxt.settext(getIntent().getExtras().get("Text"));
sp.setSelection(getIntent().getExtras().get("Value"));
```

Hope it Helps!!!

Comment: can you rephrase your answer, I can't understand it. Thanks!

Comment: its easy my friend. First of all just set flag to your intent. then see what happens??

Comment: okk then remove the flag. and do as i have said in ans. pass the edittext value and spinner value as extra in intent. and receive it in MainActivity.java and set to edittext and spinner.

Comment: you mean, from the main activity, I'll pass the value of EditText and spinner to the Search activity and then pass it again to the main activity?

Comment: if you are not storing values somewhere than yes. but why are you going back to mainactivity on click of listview item?? i mean you already have searched clinic and on clicking on list view you are gain going for search why??

Comment: Because I do thousands of clinic in my database and it is not necessary it I use spinner from it. after searching clinic, it will be setTexted to another editText from the mainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setSaveEnabled(true)` or add `android:saveEnabled="true"` to layout of Views you want data retained for.

```
MyEditText.setSaveEnabled(true);
```

or

```
<EditText
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:saveEnabled="true"/>
```

Same for Spinner , or any other View you need to retain data of.

Comment: can you show some codes for it? I can't easily understand since I am new to android.

Comment: how and where can I override the onStateInstance?